# fabric check of existing folder and make new one

Tags: python, django, fabric

In my fabfile.py I am making a directory:

```
sudo('mkdir mysite')
```

I want to check if this site exists then I want to move it to `mysite_bkup` and create `mysite`

```
env.path = '/var/www/html/{}'.format(env['project_name'])
if exists(env.path):
    sudo("mv %(path)s %(path)s + '_bkup'" % env)
```

But its giving me error... How can I change the name of it..

Thank you

Comment: Fatal error: sudo() received nonzero return code 1 while executing!

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this:

```
backup = env.path + '_bkup'
print backup
if exists(env.path):
    if exists(backup):
        sudo('rm -rf {}'.format(backup))
    sudo('mv {} {}'.format(env.path, backup))
```